# Why rxScala Observable zipWith evaluates to Observable[Nothing]

Tags: scala, reactivex, rx-scala

I tried the below:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

Observable.from(Seq(1,2)).zipWith(Observable.from(Seq(3,4)))
```

When I show the resulting type I see:

```
((Int, Int) => Nothing) => Observable[Nothing]
```

I'm trying to get into an **`Observable[Int, Int]`** , what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable[Int, Int]` doesn't make sense: `Observable` only has a single type parameter. If you want `Observable[(Int, Int)]`, you need `zip`. `zipWith` requires another argument: a function which tells you *how* to combine elements.